# Domain of definition of a certain mapping

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, smooth-manifolds, manifolds

Suppose we have a compact smooth riemannian manifold $(M,g)$ and a $\mathcal{C}^2$ diffeomorphism $f$ of this manifold.
I am studying the mapping

$$\tilde{f}(x)= \exp_{f(x)}^{-1} \circ f \circ \exp_x \colon U_x \subset T_x(M) \to T_{f(x)}(M) $$

In particular, I am trying to understand the domain of definiton of this mapping.
The question is the following:

What is the "maximal" neighbourhood in which I can define the map $\tilde{f}$ ?
In particular, how does this neighbourhood depend on the choice of the riemannian metric, on the choice of $f$ and on the choice of the point $x \in U$.
Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are interested in the radius of injectivity for the exponential map?   This is a topic of many introductory differential geometry textbooks.

Comment: Why is knowing the injectivity radius enough? I think I also need to take into account how to deal with the domain of the inverse. In other words, I think I  need also the  domain of definition of $\exp_{x}^{-1}$

Comment: I suppose I view the injectivity radius as telling you the maximal radius open ball in the domain of $exp_x^{-1}$.

Comment: If I do not have a distance in the manifold, how can I consider the concept of radius?

Comment: Do you know any introductory book for differential geometry? I am extremely new to the topic

Comment: This notion of distance is the one used in the "Hopf-Rinow Theorem".  You compute it as the shortest-length geodesic between two points (if the manifold  isn't complete you need to use infima).   Most of these references suffice: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/19505/introductory-text-on-riemannian-geometry  In that list, my preference is the Gallot, Hulin, Lafontaine text.